# How do scoring penalties work in the PvZ2 Arena?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In the Arena, I have been toying around with a few different strategies. Specifically, I've been occasionally opting to over-defend one portion of the lawn while allowing breaches on 1 or 2 lanes, the theory being that with limited sun I'd rather score a lot of points where I can and try to shore up the defenses of other lanes once I have a stronger foothold.

Additionally, I've tried strategies where I go all out on sun plants and either allow them to be eaten or dig them up for space regularly.

That said, I've been trying to figure out if I'm being penalized for this strategy.

- Is there a reduction in high-value targets when a lawnmower gets launched?
- Does falling sun reduce (or increase) when a lawnmower gets launched?
- Do penalties occur if a sun-producer is eaten/dug up?

There are a few wikia articles I've found but they only speak about the aforementioned penalties in general terms, but none seem to be specific:

- https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Arena

Given that I've had mixed results wherein sometimes the strategies above work great for my score and other times it's a disaster, I'm trying to figure out if someone can point me to what the math breakdown of the penalties are.